# Selenium Other ways to find_element for onclick

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am looking at a table that has this `<tr onclick="setValue('115751')" role="row" class="odd">` like shown below. I am trying use Selenium to find_element and click on distinct rows based on the setValue. Since I normally use xpath I tried to use that but xpath does not work because some times the order changes.

```
my_item = '//*[@id="resulttable"]/tbody/tr[1]'
mychoice = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, my_item)
mychoice.click()
```

How do I get the selenium to click my_item based on the setValue or on the "Recordation No" shown in the table?
I have a little demo content from the website below.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="display dataTable no-footer" id="resulttable" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="resulttable_info" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tr role="row">
<th>Statement</th>
<th>Recordation No</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr onclick="setValue('115751')" role="row" class="odd">
<td>2022-3301051</td>
<td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm sorting_1">
3301051</td>
<td>Submitted</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="setValue('115529')" role="row" class="even">
<td>2022-3301053</td>
<td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm sorting_1">
3301053</td>
<td>Submitted</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="setValue('115201')" role="row" class="odd">
<td>2022-3301309</td>
<td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm sorting_1">
3301309</td>
<td>Not Submitted</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="setValue('115893')" role="row" class="even">
<td>2022-3301310</td>
<td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm sorting_1">
3301310</td>
<td>Not Submitted</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="setValue('115497')" role="row" class="odd">
<td>2022-3301313</td>
<td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm sorting_1">
3301313</td>
<td>Not Submitted</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying based on the `onclick` of the tr tag, you will have to escape the quotes so  the xpath would look like this

```
my_item = "//tr[@onclick=\"setValue('115497')\"]"
```

or

```
my_item = "//tr[@onclick='setValue(\'115497\')']"
```

in case you want to put the variables directly into the string literal:

```
value = 115497
my_item = f"//tr[@onclick=\"setValue('{value}')\"]"
// or my_item = f"//tr[@onclick='setValue(\'{value}\')']"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer can you check this I got an error. `SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '$x("//tr[@onclick="setValue('115893')"]")' is not a valid XPath expression.`. I also don't understand how I would do the find_element with this statement.

Comment: oh, to be able to test your xpath in chrome browser, you have to wrap  in `$x()`. But you dont need it in python so just remove

Comment: I am looping through the table and trying to get several of them so I have this statement. `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'$x("//tr[@onclick=\"setValue({setval})\"]")')`. So the setval is the variable that holds the number.

Comment: I get a syntaxerror when I use the statement `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, $x(f"//tr[@onclick=\"setValue({setval})\"]"))`. Do I need to import something?

Comment: I updated my answer above, you should remove the `$x()`.